# How to count all the files inside Google Drive root?

Tags: google-drive

I know how to find the count of all files inside a folder in Google Drive. But I need to know the count of items that exist in the root of my Google Drive. How can I do that? I can't find an option, and I can't find the answer through search.

Comment: There is no option for this.

Comment: @serenesat, can I get to that result using Google Scripts?

Comment: I didn't see any method  to count the number of files but you can get the list of folders by [getFolders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolders%28%29) method.

Answer (score 6):

## Short Answer

Google Drive UI doesn't include a way to count files in My Unit but not in other folders.

## Alternatives

### [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFiles()

> getFiles()
>
> Gets a collection of all files in the user's Drive.

### [Google Drive for PC/Mac](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987?hl=en)

Use the Windows / Finder features to count the files for you.

**Protip:** Deselect all the folders so only files directly in My Unit will be synced. For further details, see [Choose what syncs to your computer - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375083?hl=en&ref_topic=2375186)